# Confusion QLabel and QPixmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I want to display a Pixmap into a Label on Qt.
Here is the problem, the above code doesn't display the image that I want.

Please correct me if something is wrong. I have checked again and again (even it's few lines) but it didn't lead to results!!!

```
QLabel *label;
label= new QLabel(this);
QPixmap jet("C:/images/image.jpg");
label->setPixmap(jet);
```

One other problem, it seems that it works in another machine!

Comment: Error message? Have you checked if the `QPixmap` is null?

Comment: I have no error message when building!

Comment: You mean that the image doesn't show up at all? Never ever, or are there situations where it does work?

Comment: If you set a text for your label instead of pixmap, can you see that text?

Comment: Yes, the image does work, when I do the following for example:
IplImage *IMG=cvLoadImage("C:/images/image.jpg", 1);
cvSaveImage("C:/aa.jpg", IMG);

Conclusion: it's not about the path of the image.

Comment: Yes, when I do label->setText("blabla"), it s shown up

Comment: @MelMed No, I meant runtime output into the console.  If the jpeg plugin isn't loaded, for example, it will tell you in the console.

Comment: @cmannett85 how to check the jpeg plugin?

Comment: Look at the console output!  `QPixmap::isNull()` should be true if the image could not be loaded.

Comment: did you included QPixmap class?

Comment: @Shf It wouldn't even build it that was the case.

Comment: @Shf the QPixmap is included

Comment: @cmannett85 nope, just checked, it does not even need to be included to use

Comment: @MalMed and your QLabel, did you added it to layout? A bit more code would be great.

Comment: @cmannett85 -  jet {data={...} } QPixmap
-  QPaintDevice {painters=0 } QPaintDevice
-  __vfptr 0x64e72da4 *
  [0] 0x6443105e *
  [1] 0x64442ca0 *
  [2] 0x6445084b *
  [3] 0x64450e9a *
  [4] 0x6442e273 *
  [5] 0x64429417 *
  painters 0 unsigned short
-  data {d=0x00000000 } QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<QPixmapData>
  d 0x00000000 QPixmapData *

Comment: @cmannett85 it seems that it contains lots of 0!

Comment: I have discovered other thing, I have edited my question.

Comment: Try to use a PNG file instead of JPG. If it will work, the reason is absent plugin.

Comment: @york.beta,  I have just generated its PNG file. And the image has shown off now!!! Thanks

Comment: @york.beta But now, how to include that absent plugin?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg` if you are on linux, to check supporting image formats, add ` qDebug() << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats ();`

Comment: @Shf "it does not even need to be included to use" I assure you a compiler needs to read a header file before it can use the contents.  Just because *you* don't need to include it, doesn't mean no header files have also included it.

Comment: @cmannett85 Well, it is obviously already included in QLabel or other components, becouse in test app, i didn't included it and used perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, qt builds with “-system-libjpeg”, so `sudo apt-get install libjpeg` if you are on linux, and to check supporting image formats, add 
`qDebug() << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats ();`

to add plugins to your project, go to QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/plugins or something like this, chose the version you use, and copy "plugins" folder to root of your project(more precisely - you need only "imageformats" folder, that lays within plugins), and in your main.cpp file add line `addLibraryPath` (by the way, plugin's folder contain not only dlls for release, but for debugging also, they are a bit heavy, so i would remove dlls with *d.dll, for example QtCore.dll - for release, QtCored.dll - for debugging)

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
a.addLibraryPath("plugins");
w.show();
```

Comment: it just add plugins folder to project path, so it knows, where to look for the liraries ( needed on windows computers without Qt), docs - http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qapplication.html#addLibraryPath

Comment: I'm still a newbie (3 rep.) and unable to vote but just accepted your question as the useful one.